# cakephp 4 redirect user in EventListener

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have an UserEventListener which implements EventListenerInterface.
In the event: afterLogin($event){} I would like to redirect the user if the profile is not complete, I can't figure out how to do redirect with the $event parameter

**Edit:**
here is the code of the UserEventListener:

```
<?php
namespace App\Event;
use Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Authentication\AuthenticationServiceInterface;
use Authentication\AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface;
use Authentication\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

use Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface;
use Cake\Datasource\FactoryLocator;
use Cake\Log\Log;

class UserEventListener implements EventListenerInterface
{
    public function implementedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            'Users.Authentication.afterLogin' => 'afterLogin',
            //'Users.Authentication.afterLogout' => 'afterLogout'
        ];
    }

        
    public function afterLogin($event)
    {
        $profilesTable = FactoryLocator::get('Table')->get('Profiles');
        $profiles = $profilesTable->find()        
        ->where(['user_id' => $event->getData('user')->id])
        ->order(['id' => 'DESC'])->toList();
        if((count($profiles) == 1) && $profiles[0]->mobile == "" ){            
            //-- here I would like to redirect --------
            //return $event->getSubject()->redirect(['Controller'=>'Profiles', 'action' => 'edit',$event->getData('user')->id]);            
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have implemented.

Comment: I have edited the post and inserted the code